# Streams printing and redirection

Tags: c, redirect, printf, stdout

I have a program which prints (by printf) to the `stdout` some data and also calls to function `*foo*`
which also prints to the `stdout` some data [the way (implementation) of how printing is done from *foo* is unknown and I can`t see the code of foo].

I have to redirect everything from `stdout` to `buffer` or file.  I tried to do it in several ways

1. `freopen(file.txt, stdout)` - only my code prints are written to the file.txt. What was printed from foo is lost.
2. `setbuf(buffer, stdout)` - only my code prints are written to the  buffer. What was printed from foo is appears in the stdout.(It appears on the screen)

What can explain this behavior? How can the problem be solved?

Note:This code has to work in cross-OS( lunux/wind && mac OS).I use gcc in order compile the code and I have cygwin

Comment: Do you have to do this in C? A simple bash script could just take stdout and write that to a file.

Comment: right...are you ever able to see the printed output of foo? Via what mechanism?

Comment: @brc - yes.I know what is printed from foo,when I don`t use "redirection"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that `foo` isn't using `stdio` for printing and directly calling the OS for this.

I don't know about win32, but on POSIX you could use [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) to take care of it.

```
/* Before the function foo is called, make `STDOUT_FILENO` refer to `fd` */
int fd;
fd = open(...);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

#### EDIT

Much to my surprise, <strike>[win32 has `_dup2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29)</strike> but it does something else.

Comment: I thought about this solution.But this code has to work in cross-OS( lunux/wind && mac OS).I use gcc in order compile the code and I have cygwin.

Comment: Yes but like I said it should be crossplatform so it should work on other OSes too

Comment: @Yakov Other systems (the ones you mentioned) have `dup2` :-)

Comment: `_dup2` doesn't do what you think it does. On Unix systems that's a syscall that ends up making modifications to the process's file descriptor table, so anything writing to a file will be affected. On Windows, the CRT creates the illusion of having POSIX-like file descriptors that are actually wrappers for `HANDLE`, so it has its own `int`-to-`HANDLE` mapping, and *that* is what `_dup2` affects; not the `HANDLE` itself. There is no true Windows equivalent of `dup2` as far as I know, that replaces the object backing a `HANDLE` with another `HANDLE`. (I will be very interested if there is.)

Comment: @asveikau It's good to know. I felt it was a bit fishy (I mean CreateFile makes a HANDLE and all of a sudden `dup2` takes an int ?).

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that `foo()` is printing to `stdout`?  Have you tried redirecting standard output to a file at the shell and seeing whether the output from `foo()` still appears on the screen?

If the file redirection sends `foo()`'s output to the file, then you may have to rejig the file descriptor level, as in [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar)'s answer.

If the file redirection does not send `foo()`'s output to the file, then it may be writing to `stderr` or it may be opening and using `/dev/tty` or something similar.  You can test for `stderr` by redirecting it separately from  `stdout`:

```
your_program >/tmp/stdout.me 2>/tmp/stderr.me
```

If it is opening `/dev/tty`, the output will still appear on your screen.

Which platform are you on?  If you can track system calls (`strace` on Linux, `truss` on Solaris, ...), then you may be able to see in that what the `foo()` function is doing.  You can help things by writing a message before and after calling the function, and ensuring you flush the output:

```
printf("About to call foo()\n");
fflush(0);
foo();
printf("Returned from foo()\n");
fflush(0);
```

The printf/fflush calls will be visible in the trace output, so what appears between is done by `foo()`.

Comment: +1 Indeed I am beginning to suspect the library is actually writing to `stderr`.

Comment: In some manual about foo was written that it wwrites to stdout

Comment: @Yakov: Sometimes, manuals have been erroneous.  Sometimes, manuals have been correct but the software has not implemented what the manual says the software implements.  The manual is an indicator; but the actual behaviour of the code suggests that the manual and the software are not both correct.

Comment: @Yakov: If you are planning to work across platforms, how do you obtain the different copies of `foo()` for the different machines?  Are you buying the library for each platform from the same vendor?  Have you spoken to the vendor?  Is there an alternative API to `foo()` which does much the same job but with different ways of reporting results (for example, one which allows you to specify the file stream where the results should be written)?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Yes I do see it on the screen

Answer (score 0):

> What can explain this behavior?

I have seen this sort of behavior when the code you are calling into uses a different C library than yours.  On Windows I used to see this sort of thing when one DLL is compiled with GCC and another with Visual C++.  The implementation of `stdio` for these is apparently different enough such that this can be problematic.

Another is that the code you are calling is not using `stdio`.  If you are on Unix you can use `dup2` to get around this, eg. `dup2(my_file_descriptor, 1)`.  On many implementations if you have a `FILE*` you can say `dup2(fileno(f), 1)`.  This may not be portable.

Comment: This code has to work in cross-OS( lunux/wind && mac OS).I use gcc in order compile the code and I have cygwin